# Fetching remote code/text with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

So I'm working on making a dynamic drop down select form and I need for each menu to propagate possible choices from a prebuilt chunk of html (located at, say, http://example.com/menu/choices) is there an easy way to use javascript to fetch the html of a remote page and then plug that in to the page? I know I can use .write() to insert the code, I just don't know how to fetch it.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I get errors on that URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can't use `write` to insert the code, not once the initial page rendering is complete.

### Loading Code

My first read of your question was that you wanted to load *code* — e.g., JavaScript. Here's how you do that, but see below.

The easiest way to do this is if your code exists at its source location in a JavaScript file all ready for inclusion in a file in the normal way. In that case, all you need to do is create a `script` element and add it to the document:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = /* ... the URL of the code ... */;
document.body.appendChild(script);
document.body.removeChild(script);
```

Note that last line, removing the `script` node immediately after inserting it in the document. Inserting the node is all you need to do, that immediately triggers the process by which the JavaScript file is fetched and interpreted. You can remove the script element immediately (or not, it's up to you).

In the above, I've added the element to `document.body` because it's convenient and it doesn't matter where you add it. However, most scripts you see doing this will usually add it to the `head` instead. That's fine too. More in [this article](http://proto-scripty.wikidot.com/prototype%3ahow-to-load-scripts-dynamically), although it's focussed on the Prototype library.

Speaking of libraries, all of the above notwithstanding, if you use a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries), it will probably make this (even) easier for you.

---

**Update**: Did you add the `jQuery` tag later? I didn't see it originally. With jQuery, if you're loading the script from the same origin as the document, you can use the [`getScript` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
jQuery.getScript('ajax/test.js');
// Or $.getScript('ajax/test.js');
```

**However**, `getScript` is not the same as the technique above. `getScript` will be hampered by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), whereas adding a `script` tag is not.

### Loading Markup

If you want to load HTML markup and apply it to part of a page, that's easily done with `jQuery.load`:

```
$('#someid').load("yoururl.here");
```

That will replace the contents of the element with the id "someid" with the HTML returned from the given URL. [Here's a live example](http://jsbin.com/ebama3) that loads `option`s into a `select` and [another](http://jsbin.com/ebama3/2) that loads text (a paragraph) into a div. This is easier with a library (like jQuery) because there are some issues around certain elements that libraries usually handle for you.

Comment: Nope, I put it in in the beginning :) and can I use jQuery to access html? like getHTML or something? It would just be simple source code.

Comment: @Parker: Sure. My first read of your question was that it was about *code*, but I've updated to address loading markup as well. With live examples.

Comment: @TJ: Fantastic answer, I chose you for your fast updates, extensive explanations, and live examples. Thanks much :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing you want is called AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML). If you're using jQuery:

```
$('#my-select-thingy').load('select-options.cgi');
```

or whatever flavour of server-side you prefer. You should have something like this in HTML:

```
<div id="my-select-thingy">
  <!-- select will go here -->
</div>
```

and the url above should return something like this:

```
<select>
  <option>Foo</option>
  <option>Bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks much for that snippet! I'm guessing that this is jQuery?

Comment: @Parker: That is indeed `jQuery`. It will also be hampered by the Same Origin Policy. Whether that's a problem for what you're trying to do is another matter. :-)

Comment: Yes, jQuery. All other JavaScript libraries of note today have similar functionality though; coding it from scratch is a major pain because of browser incompatibilities.

Comment: @TJ: Thanks! And I'm guessing this Same Origin Policy will keep me from loading HTML (such as http://ohiostate.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBDropDownView?jspStoreDir=ohiostate&deptId=&campusId=30747395&catalogId=10001&dojo.transport=xmlhttp&termId=44357427) ?

Comment: If you have control of your own server, you can trick your browser: at your server, pull data from the remote server, and serve it to your page. This way, the browser is still only communicating with your server. Be nice about setting a proper `UserAgent`; it would also be good to have a permission to do so (or at least not have a policy forbidding automated page accesses), otherwise you might get an IP-block.

Answer (score 1):

You're way better of using jQuery for that. Just look into the Ajax methods and you'll get the hang of it. http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Javascript usually can't access other websites for security reasons. If we could load content from wherever we wanted with a script we'd see some pretty rampant chaos. A simple solution is an iframe with the other document or just a section of it.

Does the website have anyway for you to access that info? If you can find an interface you can just get the info and stick in in the document. Otherwise you'd have to do some scraping.

Comment: How could I use greasemonkey? And yes, if theres a way I could enmass get the code for a site that would be great1

Comment: There's no problem adding scripts from other sites dynamically. In fact, that's how [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) works to get around the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: @Parker greasemonkey is a way to run javascript in your browser after a page has downloaded, but it only works on your machine. If that's what your going for then you'd just need to create a script that scraped the data.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following HTML markup

```
<div id="fakeDiv"></div>
```

you can execute an ajax request like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    dataType: "html",
    url: "http://example.com/menu/choices",
    data: {},
    success: function(response) {
        $("#fakeDiv").html('').html(response);
    },
});
```

to inject the html code returned by your url inside the DIV element.

This is jQuery code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo! Can I do this with pages that aren't on my own server?

Comment: @Parker: you're welcome. I've never done but I think you can do it without problems.